# How to sort @Html.DropDownListFor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to sort the drop down list in MVC C#.
This is my drop down list. So I want to  sort by "FULLNAME".

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.t_PEOPLE, 
                              new SelectList(Model.PEOPLE,
                                                 "KEY",
                                                 "FULLNAME", 
                                             Model.BOTKEY),
                                         new {onchange = "BusinessContact(this.value);" })
```

How can I do it??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
/* other code here.. */
new SelectList(Model.PEOPLE.OrderBy(x => x.FirstName),
                          // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this
/* rest of the code here */
```

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't do it in the view, but if you *really* want to:

1. Include System.Linq in your view by using @using System.Linq
2. Model.PEOPLE.OrderBy(p => p.YourProperty)